# Results from ANN with very random input network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, xor, backpropagation

Initially I implemented a Backpropagation network in Matlab and used it on XOR. However, now I am using to  the same network using the following input/target combination.

Inputs = `[0 0; 0 1; 1000 0; 1 1]`, Targets = `[0; 1000; 1; 0]`

And I get output as `[1;1;1;1]`

The network wasn't able to learn the network at all. Could anyone please explain why it is so? And what can I do if I to build a network that can learn such small I/O networks?

Any explanation is highly appreciated.

Regards
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like a scaling problem.  In your original XOR problems, the inputs and outputs were all on comparable scales, namely [0,1].  In your revised problem, some inputs appear to be [0,1] and some [0,1000].

The solution is to normalize the inputs to similar scales: [0,1] or [-1,1] are commonly used.
In your case, it may be sufficient to divide the inputs by 1000 to place your range into [0,1].  Don't forget to denormalize the outputs (i.e. multiply by 1000 in your case) to return to the original scale.

Comment: Thank you very much ! What do you mean by scaling problem? Cna you throw some light ?

Comment: One of your inputs is *a thousand* times larger than the other.  The inputs should be similar in size.

Comment: Thank you very much ! And no matter what I change in the network configuration, the output remains 1,1,1,1. Any reason why it doesn't change? I am a novice in this field and I was under the impression that the network weights change due to random initialization. How come I land with the same output everytime?